# Two sections on one page make fancyhdr takes the second one as page header

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I have two sections on one page. Unfortunately `fancyhdr` takes the second one as the page header, which will result in something like seen in the image below.

I want to have the **first** section as the header title (in this case: *Introduction*).

[image]

Here is the code for the above image:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\fancyplain{}{\leftmark }}
\rhead{}
\usepackage{lipsum} %only for dummy text

\begin{document}
    \section{Introduction}
        \lipsum[2]
    \section{Overview}
        \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: In typography, this is considered to be the correct behavior. The header refers to the section that ends the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`titleps`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titleps) - as an alternative to [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) - provides `\toptitlemarks` and `\bottitlemarks` to identify the top/bottom titles on a page, respectively. It should not be difficult to switch to `titleps`, in my opinion. Here's a short example that illustrates this (click the image to enlarge):

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{article}
\usepackage{titleps,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{titleps,lipsum}
\newpagestyle{main}{%
  \sethead
    {\toptitlemarks \thesection \quad \sectiontitle}% left
    {\thepage}% centre
    {\bottitlemarks \thesection \quad \sectiontitle}% right
  \setheadrule{.4pt}% Regular header rule
}
\pagestyle{main}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-3]
\section{Overview}
\lipsum[4-6]
\section{Conclusion}
\lipsum[5-9]
\end{document}
```

The above MWE produces 3 pages with headers:

```
1 Introduction       1           2 Overview
...
2 Overview           2         3 Conclusion
...
3 Conclusion         3         3 Conclusion
...
```

Obviously page 3 presents a problem. However, you might not be interested in a dictionary-style header (showing both the first and last section on the page).

See the [`titleps` documentation](http://www.tex-tipografia.com/archive/titleps.pdf) (section **4. Marks**, p 4) for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. Can I still use `fancyhdr` while using `titleps`? Because I do have a different header style for my titlepage:
`\fancypagestyle{firstPageStyle}`
`{`
   `\fancyhead[R]{ \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/header} }`
}`

Comment: @FlyingRocket: No; these packages are to be used exclusively (one *or* the other). However, `titleps` also allows you to make page styles (however many you want), just like `fancyhdr`. In my MWE, I've created the `main` page style using `\newpagestyle{main}{<page style stuff>}`. You can add `\newpagestyle{firstPageStyle}{<different stuff>}`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Now I can use `titleps` as it can also handle custom page styles :). Thank you for your help!