# header: subsection that is continued, not the one starting on the page

Tags: sectioning, header-footer

I have `\documentclass{article}` and I use fancyhdr like that:

```
\fancyhead[L]{\slshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}} 
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection\ #1}}
```

Now with a document like this:

```
2.1 some subsection
bla bla text
-- page break happens here
[HEADER: 2.2 next subsection]
a lot more text, until nearly the end of the page
2.2 next subsection
```

As you see, the header contains the name of the subsection that only starts at the bottom of the page, but all the text below the header belongs to section 2.1.

I find this irritating. Is it possible to make the header display the number and name of the section that the start of the page belongs to (in other words*, the last subsection of the preceding page)? So that in the example above, it'd say `[HEADER: 2.1 some subsection]` on the second page.

(* exception: if the 2.2 subsection started right on the top of the page, so that no text belonging to 2.1 appears on the second page, I want the header to say 2.2 as it does now)

I'm also happy about an explanation on why the default is as it is. As I said, I find it counterintuitive, but I think there's a reason for it?

Comment: You can do this with [`titleps`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titleps). If so, then `\toptitlemarks` is what you're after. See [Two sections on one page make `fancyhdr` takes the second one as page header](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97382/5764).

Comment: plain tex has an approach for this -- `\topmark` for whatever is in effect at the top of the "next" page, and `\firstmark` for whatever is the marked item first encountered on that page.  if the marked item *starts* the page, then both are the same; if there is a continuation, then they're different.  i really haven't dug into what latex has done though.  (but i was there at the "birth" of `\topmark`; it was added to satisfy a requirement that i posed to knuth in 1979.)

Comment: Thank you, Werner, that did it. If you post this as an answer, I can accept it. Or, better, close it as duplicate, but I seem to not have enough reputation for that.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: `\topmark` does not seem to work in latex, I don't re-find the source, but I just read about it while reading around on titleps

Comment: it seems that latex used to ignore it.  i find that it has been added in the package `fixltx2e`.  but the answer provided in the link by @Werner is better for you anyhow.  i will take the initiative to close this question since you suggested it.

Comment: by the way, to "ping" someone who has left a comment, put @ in front of the name; otherwise, the name is just text, and the named person won't be notified, but would just find the response by accident.

Comment: @Werner see comment above! (I cannot notify two users, but thanks barbara, in case you see this, in theory I do know :) )

Comment: @Marian: Once a question has been closed it no more answers can be added. This is not a problem as you mention the linked post helped you out.